# Incorrect virtualbox (kernel) installed for Manjaro/Arch/pacman

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, virtualbox, manjaro, pacman

I did a bad virtualbox installation on 4.19.2-1-MANJARO with pacman.

This is my initial install stdout:

```
[gloom@tacos-pc etc]$ sudo pacman -S virtualbox
error: could not register 'multilib' database (database already registered)
resolving dependencies...
:: There are 11 providers available for VIRTUALBOX-HOST-MODULES:
:: Repository extra
   1) linux316-virtualbox-host-modules  2) linux318-virtualbox-host-modules
   3) linux414-virtualbox-host-modules  4) linux419-virtualbox-host-modules
   5) linux420-virtualbox-host-modules  6) linux44-virtualbox-host-modules
   7) linux49-virtualbox-host-modules
:: Repository community
   8) linux414-rt-virtualbox-host-modules
   9) linux416-rt-virtualbox-host-modules
   10) linux418-rt-virtualbox-host-modules  11) virtualbox-host-dkms

Enter a number (default=1): 
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) linux316-3.16.62-1  linux316-virtualbox-host-modules-6.0.2-1
             virtualbox-6.0.2-1

Total Download Size:   117.19 MiB
Total Installed Size:  247.06 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
 linux316-3.16.62-1-...    55.6 MiB   598K/s 01:35 [######################] 100%
 linux316-virtualbox...   214.5 KiB   559K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 virtualbox-6.0.2-1-...    61.4 MiB   541K/s 01:56 [######################] 100%
(3/3) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(3/3) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(3/3) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(3/3) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(3/3) checking available disk space                [######################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/3) installing linux316                          [######################] 100%
>>> Updating module dependencies. Please wait ...
Optional dependencies for linux316
    crda: to set the correct wireless channels of your country [installed]
(2/3) installing linux316-virtualbox-host-modules  [######################] 100%
===> You must load vboxdrv module before starting VirtualBox:
===> # modprobe vboxdrv
(3/3) installing virtualbox                        [######################] 100%
Optional dependencies for virtualbox
    vde2: Virtual Distributed Ethernet support [installed]
    virtualbox-guest-iso: Guest Additions CD image
    virtualbox-ext-vnc: VNC server support
    virtualbox-sdk: Developer kit
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
( 1/10) Install DKMS modules
( 2/10) Updating linux316 initcpios
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux316.preset: 'default'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-3.16-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64.img
==> Starting build: 3.16.62-1-MANJARO
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [resume]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64.img
==> Image generation successful
==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux316.preset: 'fallback'
  -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-3.16-x86_64 -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64-fallback.img -S autodetect
==> Starting build: 3.16.62-1-MANJARO
  -> Running build hook: [base]
  -> Running build hook: [udev]
  -> Running build hook: [modconf]
  -> Running build hook: [block]
  -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
  -> Running build hook: [keymap]
  -> Running build hook: [resume]
  -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64-fallback.img
==> Image generation successful
( 3/10) Updating Grub-Bootmenu
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-3.16-x86_64-fallback.img
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
done
( 4/10) Updating icon theme caches...
( 5/10) Reloading system manager configuration...
( 6/10) Creating system user accounts...
( 7/10) Reloading device manager configuration...
( 8/10) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
( 9/10) Updating the desktop file MIME type cache...
(10/10) Updating the MIME type database...
```

I believe it was a bad install because when I tried to run virtualbox after installation I got an error that said:

```
Unloading modules: 
Loading modules: modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxnetadp not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.2-1-MANJARO
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxnetflt not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.2-1-MANJARO
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxpci not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.2-1-MANJARO
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.2-1-MANJARO
```

I was following the instructions listed here: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox#Install_VirtualBox and I selected the default kernel option (first prompt during install) instead of selecting one based on my manjaro install for `linux*-virtualbox-host-modules`.

Then I tried to uninstall virtualbox by using `packman -Rs virtualbox`.  However, when I try to start again, I am not given the prompt to select my `linux*-virtualbox-host-modules` version.  When I try to install again, it defaults to `virtualbox-6.0.2-1`.  Obviously I'm not great at installing things. Then I moved `linux${wrong}-virtualbox-host-modules` to the side and tried installing again... It did not prompt me for the version number but I let the install anyway.

When I tried to run the second install, I got this error:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.19.2-1-MANJARO) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox)
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxGlobal.so)
```

Then I tried to `pacman -S linux419-virtualbox-host-modules` and it ran successfully but I still have the error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the `virtualbox-host-modules` package recursively, which also gets rid of the other package.

You can do so by running:
`sudo pacman -Rcs virtualbox-host-modules`

Then, reinstall the package:
`sudo pacman -Syu virtualbox-host-modules`

Doing a `sudo modprobe -a vboxsf` confirmed that this worked for me.